# Javacv face recognition - mismatch in methods arguments types

Tags: java, javacv, face-recognition

I'm trying to run a face recognition example using javacv, but there is a mismatch in the methods arguments types.
I'm using the following maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

I'm referring to this example: http://pcbje.github.io/misc/2012/12/01/doing-face-recognition-with-javacv.html

Imports:

```
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_face.createFisherFaceRecognizer;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.cvLoadImage;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.MatVector;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_face.FaceRecognizer;
```

The only difference is that they are using *com.googlecode.javacv*, but as far as I understand this is old. However I downloaded those jars from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavacvjar.htm, but I'm still not able to compile successfully.

Can you please advice. Thank you.

**[SOLVED] - Please refer to [this example](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/OpenCVFaceRecognizer.java)**

Comment: can you add also error message

Comment: error messages:
1.
images.put(counter, grayImg);

The method put(long, opencv_core.Mat) in the type opencv_core.MatVector is not applicable for the arguments (int, opencv_core.IplImage)
2.
faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);

The method train(opencv_core.MatVector, opencv_core.Mat) in the type opencv_face.FaceRecognizer is not applicable for the arguments (opencv_core.MatVector, int[])
3.
int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(greyTestImage);

The method predict(opencv_core.Mat) in the type opencv_face.FaceRecognizer is not applicable for the arguments (opencv_core.IplImage)

Comment: did you fix this? im facing same problem, trying to replace all changes but i can't replace old predict(IplImage, int[], double[]); by this one opencv_face.predict(Mat src, int[] label, double[] confidence);

Comment: @Kuriel - try first converting IplImage to Mat: 
`IplImage greyTestImage = IplImage.create(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
**Mat imgMat = new Mat(img);**
int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(imgMat);`

Comment: @Kuriel - Please see https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/OpenCVFaceRecognizer.java